# How can I create a c++ header file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, header-files

I have a program with 3 files, and when IrRun the program via Code Runner it keeps printing errors.The icon for the "Log.hpp" file is C, not C++. It doesnt matter if I rename it to Log.h or anything, it seems that I cant create a c++ header file in vscode.

The 3 files are:

1. main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "log.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    InitLog();
    Log("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

2. log.cpp

```
#include "log.hpp"
#include <iostream>

void InitLog() {
    Log("Initializing Log");
}

void Log(const char *message) {
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}
```

3. log.hpp

```
#pragma once

void InitLog();
void Log(const char *message);
```

The error mesages are:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:5:5: error: 'InitLog' was not declared in this scope
     InitLog();
     ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:6:5: error: 'Log' was not declared in this scope
     Log("Hello World");
```

Need help.

Comment: Is this relevant? [What are the dangers of using #pragma once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830610/what-are-the-dangers-of-using-pragma-once) I presume you don't get an error message saying `log.hpp not found`. Note that if the header only contains function declarations, and does not `#include` other headers, you can include it multiple times.

Comment: I tried using the other method showed in there(aka using ifndef ect.) but the error is still the same.

Comment: Where is `log.hpp`? Do you have multiple `log.hpp` files on your system?

Comment: It should not matter *what* you call the included file.

Comment: I do not have any other header files in my system.

Comment: It's only compiling `main` there must be some setting you need to change so `log.cpp` is also compiled and linked.

Comment: Have you remembered to *save* the header file? If you look at it from some other program, does it look like you expect?

Comment: Yeah, I saved all the 3 files in my program.

Comment: By the way, the code you show doesn't match the errors you get. The error for `InitLog` is reported on line 5, which is `int main() {`. And the error for the `Log` call is on line 6 which is the `InitLog` call in the shown code. Please [edit] your question and copy-paste the actual code generating the errors.

Comment: Although considering the lines for the error report is shifted up by one from the shown code, it's possible to guess that the `main.cpp` file you're building is missing the `#include "Log.hpp"` line. Double-check that! And not only in your editor, go to the file on the disk and open it in another program.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Windows? Which compiler? Do you have Microsoft Build Tools installed or even Visual Studio? Are you using gcc or clang?

You must start VS Code from a developer prompt: Open a developer prompt console, navigate to the folder where you code is. Then enter

```
code .
```

Visual Studo Code will then open with the environment set up. Then open a terminal inside VSCode using Control-` and try

```
cl /EHsc main.cpp log.cpp
```

And it will create `main.exe`. You can run it in the terminal and it will not close... Next time you open the project you can just open the folder in VS Code, since it would then already have the json config files created

VS Code is just an IDE. So compilers must be installed and also extensions. And some JSON files and tasks must be set up. It is sometimes simple, sometimes not so simple, I believe. But doing that you will then have a powerful editor and an unbelievably flexible environment, since you can for instance run and debug code in nodejs or C or C++ or anything and even in Linux without leaving the session on your casual Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about a specific vscode plugin called Code Runner. It's not really related to vscode. The way how Code Runner is designed will never work for multiple C++ source files. It's not the right tool for the job.
Perhaps you'd better off with Microsofts CMake Tools package for vscode. It does require you to create your own CMakeLists.txt file though. In your case you'd need nothing more than:

```
add_executable(log
    main.cpp
    log.cpp
)
```

Comment: I added the file CMakeLists.txt with your given code inside of it, but when I try to run it, the same thing happens. What am I missing?

Comment: Don't use Code Runner but the CMake Tools instead. After installing it, reloading vscode, you should have a run and debug button in the bottom blue bar. Press it, select a kit and run it. Read the Getting Started section in the documentation: https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good fix but you can include "log.cpp" itself. It works for me.

Comment: It does work but feels not legal to do haha.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you can properly configure your C++ project using [CMake](https://cmake.org/) and [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/).

### Project Structure

Your project's file/folder structure should be like this.

```
project
 |
 |- log
 |   |
 |   |- log.hpp
 |   |- log.cpp
 |   |- CMakeLists.txt
 |
 |- other_module
 |   |
 |   |- other_module.hpp
 |   |- other_module.cpp
 |   |- CMakeLists.txt
 |
 |- main.cpp
 |- CMakeLists.txt
```

Notice the extra `CMakeLists.txt` files in every folder. To put it in **simple** (and potentially incorrect) words, CMake scripts basically tell the compiler where all the relevant files are and which settings to use when compiling them. The `CMakeLists.txt` alongside `main.cpp` is the root CMake file.

### CMake Scripts

The contents of the root `CMakeLists.txt` would be like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)

get_filename_component(PROJECT_NAME ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} NAME)
project(${PROJECT_NAME} VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
add_subdirectory(log)
add_subdirectory(other_module)
```

And the contents of the `CMakeLists.txt` files in each folder:

```
get_filename_component(CURRENT_DIR_NAME ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} NAME)
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${CURRENT_DIR_NAME}.cpp)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE .)
```

### Compilation

Then in the terminal, use CMake and Ninja to compile it.

```bash
cmake -G Ninja -B build
ninja -C build
```

And your executable would be in a folder named `build`.

```
project
 |
 |- build
 |   |- some_files ...
 |   |- project.exe <----- Your executable
 |
 |- log
 |   |- some_files ...
 |
 |- other_module
 |   |- some_files ...
 |
 |- some_files ...
```

The good thing about this approach is that you can add very complex folder structures to your project and it would still be this easy to use.

And you can use it in a similar way on any OS, Windows, MacOS or Linux.

I have made a [VSCode extension, "C Toolkit"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UsmanMehmood.c-toolkit) with which you can create these CMake projects, compile, run and debug them very easily. Although right now it only works with **C applications, and not C++**, the support for C++ is in the works. :)